# xamarin android button click is not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am new in xamarin. so just trying to make basic application. but button click is not working i.e. when click from application code is not executed

MainActivity.cs

```
StartActivity(typeof(LoginActivity));
```

LoginActivity.cs

```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.loginButton);
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                save();
            };
        }
    }
    public void save()
    {
        string ab = "asbs";
        Console.WriteLine("Working");
    }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that button is not null?

Comment: Make sure `loginButton` is the actual identifier for the button you're targeting.

Comment: @VenkyDhana Yes it is not null

Comment: @user3185569 id is also same

Comment: Why do you write to a console when clicking a button on your phone? try to change the text of the button when clicking on it

Comment: @Radinator That portion is not working.! even on debugging debugger not going on click

Comment: `if (button != null)` maybe this line if not passed, and the button i null?

Answer (score 1):

Declare the following method:

```
public void save(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Add code to run when the button is clicked here

}
```

To attach the method to the click event, include the following in your code:

```
if (BtnSave != null)
{
    BtnSave.Click += save;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
// set onclick listener here, by deleting some process
    button.Click += delegate {
        loginButtonClick();
    };

public void loginButtonClick()
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Proceed to Login ", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```